# Opening and Closing balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the opening and closing balance in my query.

This is my query

```
SELECT 
[Voucher].[TransactionCode] [VoucherNo], 
SUM([Detail].[DrAmount]) [DrAmount], SUM([Detail].[CrAmount]) [CrAmount]

FROM
[FICO].[tbl_TransactionMaster] [Voucher], [FICO].[tbl_TransactionDetail] [Detail]

WHERE  
[Detail].[TransactionCode] = [Voucher].[ID] 

GROUP BY [Voucher].[TransactionCode]
```

The output I'm getting is this.

```
VoucherNo            DrAmount   CrAmount
FMS-CRV-1-1-Doc--18  12         12
FMS-CRV-2-1-Doc--18  999        999
FMS-CRV-3-1-Doc--18  18000      18000
FMS-JV-10-1-Doc--18  3000       3000
FMS-JV-1-1-Doc--18   99351      99351
```

The output I'm expecting is like this

```
VoucherNo            DrAmount   CrAmount   Amount
FMS-CRV-1-1-Doc--18  12         12         12
FMS-CRV-2-1-Doc--18  999        999        1011
FMS-CRV-3-1-Doc--18  18000      18000      19011
FMS-JV-10-1-Doc--18  3000       3000       22011
FMS-JV-1-1-Doc--18   99351      99351      121362
```

Let's say there was one more voucher worth 1000 saved in DB before that than it should be like this

```
VoucherNo            DrAmount   CrAmount   Amount
FMS-CRV-1-1-Doc--18  12         12         1012
FMS-CRV-2-1-Doc--18  999        999        2011
FMS-CRV-3-1-Doc--18  18000      18000      20011
FMS-JV-10-1-Doc--18  3000       3000       21011
FMS-JV-1-1-Doc--18   99351      99351      122362
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Why are the `Dr` and `Cr` amounts always the same?

Comment: I belive that there is something wrong in the data you provide cause this expecting results can be returned with a simple query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well actually there is a check on form that unless Debit and Credit amount is not equal it won'y let the record save. I'm not sure what is the business logic behind I just have to fetch the data and create a report.

Comment: @Sami what simple could that be to get the sum of the previous row and the current and so on

Comment: BTW, **do not** use old style joins.

Comment: @Sami I'd really appreciate if you could help me by bringing on the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use proper explicit `JOIN`s (i.e. `INNER JOIN`)

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
           td.TransactionCode, SUM(td.DrAmount) as DrAmount, SUM(td.CrAmount) as CrAmount
    FROM [FICO].[tbl_TransactionMaster] tm
    INNER JOIN [FICO].[tbl_TransactionDetail] td ON td.TransactionCode = tm.ID
    GROUP BY td.TransactionCode
)

SELECT *,
        SUM(CrAmount) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionCode 
                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Amount
FROM CTE
```

As for the desired result you would need to use *window functions*  to sum with previous amount.